# C# generic. Можно ли создать список, состоящий из экземпляров обобщенного класса?

Tags: c#, list, generics

Есть обобщенный *абстрактный* класс, у которого есть абстрактные методы:

```
public abstract class SomeType<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public abstract T GetRandom();
    //...
}
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы экземпляры данного класса могли помещаться в один список, будь то `SomeType<int>` или `SomeType<float>`. Ожидается следующее:

```
var list = new List<SomeType<T>>();
```

Есть ли возможность сделать что-то подобное средствами языка C#?

**UPD.** Возможно, я нашел решение, но не уверен, что оно верное (пока не попробовал). Думаю использовать тип `dynamic`:

```
var list = new List<SomeType<IComparable<dynamic>>>();
```

Comment: Тип заранее задан?

Comment: @Monomax в том то и дело, что нет. Тип может быть `int`, `float`, `bool`, `double`.

Comment: Без `dynamic` или `object` решения я не вижу. Если бы это было возможно, какого статического типа был бы элемент массива?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, пока в generic нельзя задать ограничения на `int`, `float` и т.д.

Comment: @VladD, в теории можно `SomeType<T>` чтобы либо реализовал интерфейс не генериковский либо наследовался от класса негенериковского тогда базовый класс можно будет указать

Comment: @Grundy: Это да, вот я пытаюсь намекнуть ТСу на причины невозможности

Comment: @VladD, а dynamic ты куда хотел? `List<SomeType<dynamic>>` или `List<dynamic>`? Первый вариант так же не работает при попытке добавить SomeType<int> например

Comment: Второй, конечно. Нам же нужен общий базовый тип? Работать будет, понятно, медленно.

Comment: @VladD, там в этом случае и object Достаточно тогда

Comment: @Grundy: Но я не думаю, что ТС будет доволен, если операций над объектом провести будет нельзя

Comment: @VladD, ну он ж все равно будет получать этот объект, а сохранить его в переменную dynamic можно независимо от того какой тип у списка указан

Comment: @Grundy Тип object - сразу нет, поскольку мне нужно обращаться к методам класса.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, ты  все равно будешь получать элемент списка, а сохранить его в переменную dynamic можно независимо от того какой тип у списка указан.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы собрались не просто хранить любые объекты в списке, а что-то с ними делать - вам нужен вам нужен общий базовый класс или интерфейс для них, куда вы соберете проводимые над элементами списка операции:

```
public abstract class SomeType
{
    // ...
}

public class SomeType<T> : SomeType where T : IComparable<T>
{
    // ...
}

// ...

var list = new List<SomeType>();
```

В некоторых случаях вам подойдет тип object:

```
var list = new List<object>();
```

Comment: Забыл сказать, что класс SomeType<T> - абстрактный. Да, мне необходимо с данными объектами "что-то делать". Но что, если у меня весь интерфейс описан в этом классе `SomeType<T>` и он абстрактный? Мне нужно будет сделать его неабстрактным, создать необходимый интерфейс и реализовать интерфейс в классе `SomeType`?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko код который работает с элементами списка знает T? Если нет - вам **придется** придумать другой интерфейс. Если да - то вы можете хранить object и приводить тип к `SomeType<T>`

Comment: нет, код не знает

Comment: @AndreiKhotko тогда ваша настоящая проблема - в том, что у вас нет правильного интерфейса, которым можно пользоваться не зная T. Когда вы ее решите - то и проблема хранения пропадет.

Comment: Понял вас. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

`SomeType<int>` и `SomeType<float>` – это **разные** классы, поэтому их нельзя поместить в один типизированный список, только список `object`.

При использовании generic: `new List<SomeType<T>>();` тип должен явно указываться, поэтому приведенная запись корректна только в случае если где-то объявлен тип `T`, либо в случае когда он берется снаружи, например:

```
class A<T>{
    public void F(){
        var list = new List<SomeType<T>>();
    }
}
```

либо из функции

```
public void F<T>(){
    var list = new List<SomeType<T>>();
}
```